# Dot confused with Times in pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching

I would like to write some rules that distinguish between the `Times` and `Dot` functions, but I get the following behavior,

```
  Clear[f,m,n];
  f[Dot[a__]] := {"Dot", a};
  f[Times[a__]] := {"Times", a};

  f[Dot[m,n]]
```

> ```
>  {"Times",Dot[m,n]}
> ```

Shouldn't I get

> ```
>  {"Dot",m,n}
> ```

Comment: Take a look at `?? f`. It is becasue `Dot[a__]` evaluates.

Comment: There should be a better duplicate but this one is good enough.